I need to recover files from a computer that I deleted files from and then emptied the recycle bin on
Work sent me a new windows laptop. I thought I moved all of the files that I needed, but I now need to recover some more.
When I thought I had gotten them all I deleted the files from the old laptop. The drive is using bitlocker, but it still boots and I have access to the drive by logging in. I want to try to ask the questions as to what might be the best method without taking a chance a damaging the files before I try to restore.
I have a copy of the newest version of Hirens boot CD, but have not ran anything from the USB against it yet to try to preserve anything I can. If there is a better recovery program or method than the USB let me know.

Data recovery on a encrypted drive is not possible, your drive would be inaccessible to the environment, if you attempted to use Hirens BootCD PE. Any tools within Windows, the only place the drive would not accessible, would be ineffective. The data you wish to restore cannot be restored given the fact BitLocker is involved.

If you can boot and log into the old PC, and if the files are in the Recycle Bin, then just restore them. Otherwise, they're gone.

if you can login to the system
use a recovery tool like Piriform Recuva
